# como extraer listas de ficheros

Tags: python, lista, txt, read

como puedo convertir a lista en python al leer un fichero que contiene listas de la forma:
[image: archivo.txt]

lista=[(a,1), (b,2), (c,3), (d,4)]

al leerlo normalmente se lee como cadena de texto , y yo quiero ponerlo en tipo lista

```
archivo = open('gg.txt','r')
cadena1 = archivo.read()
lista=cadena1[6:-1].split()
archivo.close()
print(lista)
```

resultado:
**['(a,1),', '(b,2),', '(c,3),', '(d,4)']**
y lo que quisiera es :
**[("a",1), ("b",2), ("c",3), ("d",4)]**

pueden decirme la manera mas rapida de hacerlo pf

Comment: Hola ¿todas las lineas empiezan por `lista=`? si es así tu slicing debería ser `[6:-1]` no `[9:-1]`, `[9:-1]` para ese ejemplo generaría `[',1),', '(b,2),', '(c,3),', '(d,4)]']`, ¿o es realemnte `lista = [(a,1), (b,2), (c,3), (d,4)]` ? la linea (los dos espacios alrededor del =)

Comment: Tienes razon es [6:-1]    .Ah y son cientos de listas diferentes ,pero los nombres se repíten de tres en tres..ejm:  rc=[]\n;rr=[]\n;ra=[]\n; rc=[]\n;rr=[]\n;ra=[],etc

Comment: por eso no quiero poner esas listas en el programa por que lo haria muy pesado

Answer (score 1):

La estructura del archivo es muy mala para parsear de forma eficiente, por ejemplo, si la lista tuviera las cadenas acotadas sería muy simple con `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("[('a',1), ('b',2), ('c',3), ('d',4)]")
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)
```

al no tenerlas es imposible usarla ya que no es la representación válida de una lista Python.

Una opción es usar `ast.parse`, el parser considerá las cadena como a nombres:

```
import ast

with open('gg.txt', 'r') as file:
    for linea in file:
        parsed = ast.parse(linea)
        lista = [tuple(el.id if isinstance(el, ast.Name) else el.value
                       for el in tree.elts) for tree in parsed.body[0].value.elts
                 ]
        print(lista)
```

> ```
> [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
> ```

Comment: Las listas de los archivos son editables, entonces solo tendria que poner las letras en comillas y utilizar el  ast.literal_eval.   MUCHAS GRACIAS, y por cierto amigo donde aprendiste python , o solo se perfecciona con el tiempo (lo digo por la manera de programar en la anterior pregunta). sds

Comment: Hola Norvin, obviamente `literal_eval` es más simple, puedes convertir una lista a una cadena que pueda luego volverse a reconstruir con `repr(lista)`, esa cadena `literal_eval` debe poder convertirla en una lista de vuelta sin problemas. Aún así tienes muchos métodos más elaborados que un simple archivo de texto, puedes mirarte [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) por ejemplo, que permite serializar objetos Python arbitrarios. Además tienes  CSV o JSON o una BD como SQLite3 incluida en Python, etc

Comment: En cuanto  a dónde aprendí Python, pues  en mi caso la mayoría es autodidacta en el caso concreto de Python, StackOverflow, documentación oficial, algún que otro libro sobre temas específicos y programar mucho cometiendo muchos errores  y barbaridades... XD. Obviamente se pule con el tiempo como todo,  incluso respondiendo aquí se aprende más de los que parece ya que muchas veces se te plantean preguntas que tu no te has planteado nunca o sobre temas que no has profundizado y te hacen pensar e investigar.